# ValueEventListener voltando null?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Estou mexendo com a API de um site e de lá eu pego informações de um determinado item de uma lista de itens que veio da API e salvo no banco de dados do Firebase, agora estou querendo pegar essas informações do Firebase para utilizá-las, mas não estou conseguindo de jeito nenhum... Agora o Log que tenho ai não está imprimindo e quando consigo fazê-lo imprimir ele mostra null. Se puderem me ajudar ficarei agradecido!

**Firebase**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**ComicvineModel**

```
private Long id;
private String name;
private String api_detail_url;

public ComicVineModel() {
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getApi_detail_url() {
    return api_detail_url;
}

public void setApi_detail_url(String api_detail_url) {
    this.api_detail_url = api_detail_url;
}
```

**VolumeAdapter** (onde estou tentando pegar os dados)

```
private ArrayList<VolumeModel> volume = new ArrayList<>();
private Context context;
private FirebaseAuth autenticacao;
private DatabaseReference firebase;
private VolumeModel volumeModel = new VolumeModel();
private ComicVineModel comicVineModel = new ComicVineModel();
private ArrayList<ComicVineModel> listaVineModel = new ArrayList<ComicVineModel>();;
private ValueEventListener eventListenerVolume;


public VolumeAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<VolumeModel> volume) {
    this.volume = volume;
    this.context = c;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemLista = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_volume, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemLista);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    volumeModel = volume.get(position);
    firebase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("volume");

    holder.nome.setText(volumeModel.getName());
    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(volume.get(position).getImage().getThumb_url())
            //.placeholder(R.drawable.default_hero)
            .error(R.drawable.default_hero)
            .into(holder.imageView);
    holder.ano.setText(volumeModel.getStart_year());
    holder.edicoes.setText(volumeModel.getCount_of_issues());
    holder.editora.setText(volumeModel.getPublisher().getName());


    holder.estrela.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            holder.estrela.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_star_black_24dp));

            //pega a posição marcada e seta essas informações para irem pro banco
            comicVineModel.setId(volume.get(position).getId());
            comicVineModel.setName(volume.get(position).getName());
            comicVineModel.setApi_detail_url(volume.get(position).getApi_detail_url());

            //salva a revista no Firebase no formato de: colecao - id da revista - dados do volume
            DatabaseReference firebaseSalvaRevista = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(usuario());
            firebaseSalvaRevista.child("colecao").child(comicVineModel.getId().toString()).setValue(comicVineModel);

            Toast.makeText(context, comicVineModel.getName() + " está nos favoritos!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    eventListenerVolume = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot dados : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                comicVineModel = dados.getValue(ComicVineModel.class);
                listaVineModel.add(comicVineModel);
                Log.i("teste", "teste: " + comicVineModel);
            }
            VolumeAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };
    firebase.addValueEventListener(eventListenerVolume);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return volume.size();
}

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView nome;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private TextView ano;
    private TextView edicoes;
    private TextView editora;
    private ImageView estrela;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        nome = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idNomeRevista);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idImagemVolume);
        ano = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idAno);
        edicoes = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idEdicoes);
        editora = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idEditora);
        estrela = itemView.findViewById(R.id.idEstrela);
    }
}

public String usuario(){
    autenticacao = ConfigFirebase.getFirebaseAutenticacao();
    String usuario = autenticacao.getCurrentUser().getEmail().toString();

    usuario = Base64Custom.codificarBase64(usuario);

    return usuario;
}
```

Comment: No seu código, você acede ao nó "volume", mas  a imagem do seu banco de dados não mostra esse nó

Answer (score 0):

Tinha exatamente o mesmo problema. Dentro do Evento a lista é alimentada. Porém em outro ponto da mainactivitie a lista sempre esá vazia....

O problema está no fato de que a operação no Firebase é assincrona e quando você avalia o conteudo da lista a "task" ainda não terminou.

Solucionei o problema criando um Objeto listener com uma interface "done" que sobrescrevo ao registar o listener

Classe MeuListener:
package com.mfcapelo.projetob;

public class MeuListener {

```
private static MeuListener instance;
private EventListener eventListener;

public static MeuListener getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new MeuListener();
    }
    return instance;
}

public void registerEvent(EventListener eventListener) {
    this.eventListener = eventListener;
}

public void unRegisterEvent() {
    this.eventListener = null;
}

public void emitterDone(Imagem img) {
    this.eventListener.done(img);
}

public interface EventListener {
    void done(Imagem img);
}
```

}

No OnStart da activitie instanciamos e registramos o listener ...

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    meuListener = MeuListener.getInstance();
    meuListener.registerEvent(new MeuListener.EventListener() {
        @Override
        public void done(Imagem img) {

            listaImagens.add(img);
            Log.d("Test", "Executou o evento:" + listaImagens.size() );

        }
    });
}
```

no OnStop tiro o listener da memória 
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

```
    meuListener.unRegisterEvent();
}
```

E finalmente dentro do retorno do Firebase eu aciono o listner

```
   ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    Imagem img = postSnapshot.getValue(Imagem.class);
                    /* Aqui utilizamos a interface */
                    meuListener = MeuListener.getInstance();
                    meuListener.emitterDone(img);

                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d("getDadosUsuarioLogado: ", databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    };
    reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(postListener);
```

Utilizei o meu caso, mas a solução para o seu segue o mesmo padrão.

Espero ter ajudado.

Obrigado,

Comment: Favor fazer o [tour] e ler a [ask]. Esta é uma área de respostas, não de perguntas.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Primeiro, há um erro grande no seu código, não faça chamadas ao *Real-time Database*
dentro do seu `adapter`, dessa forma você não conseguirá tratar devidamente o retorno da chamada e o ciclo de vida da `Activity`.

Segundo, você tenta acessar um nó que não existe no banco.

E terceiro, as chamadas ao banco são assíncronas, então você precisará utilizar uma forma de obter esse dados no momento em que chegarem, independente se são simultaneamente ou daqui à 30 segundos. Para isso, veja [Como retorna um objeto utilizando addListenerForSingleValueEvent do fire base?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/372475/como-retorna-um-objeto-utilizando-addlistenerforsinglevalueevent-do-fire-base/372587?noredirect=1#comment742710_372587)

- Para futuras buscas por soluções.