# Como retorna um objeto utilizando addListenerForSingleValueEvent do fire base?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Olá, gostaria de sabe se é possível retorna um objeto utilizando Query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent() do firebase, segue código de exemplo...

```
public static Passageiro getDadosUsuarioLogado() {
    DatabaseReference reference = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseDatabase();
    Query query = reference.child("passageiros").orderByChild("id").equalTo(getIdentificadorUsuario()).limitToFirst(1);
    final Passageiro passageiro = new Passageiro();
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                passageiro = dataSnapshot.getValue(Passageiro.class);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d("getDadosUsuarioLogado: ", databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
    return passageiro;
}
```

Comment: Olá Joab! Você poderia ser mais claro? Como você mesmo fez no código de exemplo, o método `getValue()` da classe `DataSnapshot`, retorna justamente um objeto da classe que você  passa como parâmetro.

Comment: opa, gostaria de saber como eu faço para retorna o valor fora do método onDataChange, pois toda vez que eu chamo esse método ele me retorna vazio.

Answer (score 0):

Quando você chama `getDadosUsuarioLogado()`, o retorno sempre será `null` devido a chamada ao banco de dados ser assíncrona. Para que você possa obter o objeto retornado, faça o seguinte:

Crie uma interface:

```
public interface Observer<T> {
     void onEvent(T data);
}
```

Utilizaremos ela para sermos notificados quando o objeto for finalmente retornado. Depois reescreva seu método:

```
public static void getDadosUsuarioLogado(Observer<Passageiro> observer) {
    DatabaseReference reference = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebaseDatabase();
    Query query = reference.child("passageiros").orderByChild("id").equalTo(getIdentificadorUsuario()).limitToFirst(1);

    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                Passageiro passageiro = dataSnapshot.getValue(Passageiro.class);
                /* Aqui utilizamos a interface */
                observer.onEvent(passageiro);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.d("getDadosUsuarioLogado: ", databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

Eu modifiquei seu método para que possamos obter o objeto de forma "assíncrona". Removi o retorno já que não precisaremos mais e removi também a criação da instância do passageiro, já que o `getValue()` retorna uma.

E para finalizar, faça sua `activity` implementar a interface para "observar" quando o valor "chegar":

```
public class NomeDaSuaActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Observer<Passageiro> {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        SuaClasse.getDadosUsuarioLogado(this) // Referência para a interface Observer
    }

    /* ... */

    public void onEvent(Passageiro data) {
       // Tá ai, faça o que você quiser com o objeto
    }
}
```

Essa é uma das melhores formas de obter dados de forma assíncrona. Eu utilizei essa técnica até um tempo atrás quando comecei a migrar meu projeto para os novos componentes de arquitetura do Android como o LiveData, ViewlModel e o Repository. Espero que isso ajude e qualquer dúvida é só comentar.

Comment: deu certo, muito obrigadoooooooooo

Comment: Fico grato em ter te ajudado. Marque minha resposta como certa, isso me ajuda =)